# How to use the last 2 or 3 Characters of a String to Identify or as an Indicator for a Category

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dashboard

I have to deal with inventory or even identify the product that comes in.
Sometimes the manufacture is lazy and forgets about providing the category for the item within the box or cargo, however.

I was wondering if it is possible to write an Excel formula to identify the category of the items within the box by reading the string of characters. These are the parameters:

1. If the last 2 or 3 numbers add up to 17 then it is a Keyboard
2. If the last 2 or 3 numbers add up to 18 then it is a Mouse
3. If the last 3 characters are ABC, ABc, abc then it is a Book.

Would it be possible to write an Excel formula to identify that item as a Keyboard, Mouse or Book?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Order Received | Tag | Category |
| **2** | 1 | Qwerty89 | KeyBoard |
| **3** | 2 | Asdfg98 |  |
| **4** | 3 | ZXcvb89 |  |
| **5** | 4 | Yuiop557 |  |
| **6** | 5 | Hjkl;'099 | Mouse |
| **7** | 6 | Nm,./][333 |  |
| **8** | 7 | PoiuyABC | Book |
| **9** | 8 | TrewqAbc |  |
| **10** | 9 | GfdsaabC |  |
| **11** | 10 | Bvcxz449 |  |

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide to make my job a little easier.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, next time you take a screenshot, make it about what's on your sheet, not the entire sheet, look at all that white-space D:

Comment: @Notus_Panda thank you for the reminder! I have not posted in awhile and totally forogt about the forum etiquette! :P

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SWITCH(MMULT(IFERROR(--LEFT(RIGHT(B2:B11,{3,2,1})),0),{1;1;1}),17,"Keyboard",18,"Mouse",IF(RIGHT(B2:B11,3)="abc","Book",""))
```

---

For fun, but untested; since Python is now integrated within Excel, try to use the `=PY()` formula and apply the following (rookie?) code:

```
def y(z):
    s = sum(map(int,[*z]))
    return 'Keyboard' if s==17 else 'Mouse' if s==18 else ''

df = xl("B1:B11", headers = True)
df.Tag.str.replace(r'.*?(\d{1,3})$',r'\1').apply(lambda x: 'Book' if x[-3:].lower()=='abc' else (y(x) if x.isdigit() else ''))
```

Comment: `LEFT(RIGHT(B2:B11,{3,2,1}))` love it!

Comment: @JvdV I tried both of your formulas and I ended up with SPILL errors. I am sure it is user errow on my end. Am I missing something? I tried adding a picture to this thread but I dont see an Add Image button anymore?

Comment: Only use the formula in `C2`, don't drag it down. Also, if there is any other value in any of the cells in range `C3:C11` it will return this spill error. @QED_Millenium

Answer (score 1):

`=MAP(B2:B11,LAMBDA(b,IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(b)),SWITCH(SUM(IFERROR(--MID(b,LEN(b)-(ROW(1:3)-1),1),0)),17,"Keyboard",18,"Mouse",""),IF(RIGHT(b,3)="ABC","Book",""))))`

[image]

Comment: Good Morning P.b I tried just copying and pasting the formula into C2 for use. I must not understand LAMDA fully with the arrays and what "b" means in your formula. Would you mind providing a little bit of explanation? I tried YT videos in understanding LAMDA a little bit better but still kind of struggling actually I see a RED box across my Excel sheet covering Rows 1 ~ 3.

Comment: LAMBDA is used for iteration. With helper MAP it will cause the calculations used after the Lambda to be performed cell by cell (row by row in this case). The range `B2:B11` is declared as `b` in the lambda and is to be seen as the cell by cell reference to the range. So first it calculates with the value of `B2` next with `B3` all the way down to `B11` the result is spilled over the same size as the range used for calculation. Make sure all cells `C3:C11` are true empty (delete content) and use this formula in `C2` only. It'll spill with a blue surroundings in `C2:C11` as shown in the picture

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(B2)),SWITCH(SUM(IFERROR(--MID(B2,LEN(B2)-(ROW($1:$3)-1),1),0)),17,"Keyboard",18,"Mouse",""),IF(RIGHT(B2,3)="ABC","Book",""))` would be the non-lambda version for `C2` you need to drag down.

Answer (score 1):

I love the `MMULT(LEFT`-part from @JvdV :-)

But I would suggest to use a mapping table for the categories:

```
=LET(d,A2:A11,
λcheckSum,LAMBDA(d,MMULT(IFERROR(--(LEFT(RIGHT(d,{3,2,1}))),0),{1;1;1})),
dEnhanced,MAP(λcheckSum(d),d,LAMBDA(cs,b,IF(cs>0,cs,RIGHT(b,3)))),
XLOOKUP(dEnhanced,checkSum[checksum],checkSum[category],"-",0))
```

[image]

Comment: Ike I love your checksum idea because I was just thinking about a second check for totals when I get a manifest or an inventory list.